# Navbar desaparece al redimensionar

Tags: html, css

Al reducir el tamaño de la pantalla, me desaparece la navbar por completo y necesito que se haga responsive.

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="header-container header">
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"> <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo".png" /> </a>
            <div class="header-right">
                <a class="navbar-item" href="#about">Nosotros</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="#calidad">Calidad</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="#products">Productos</a>
                <a class="navbar-item" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.header-right {
display: none;

display: block;
float: right;
padding: 6px 20px;

}

.navbar-item {
color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-item:hover {
color: #58d5f7;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende tu duda, por favor se mas descriptivo

Comment: @BetaM listo ya la edite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes los siguientes errores:

- Tienes una instrucción que lo pretende mostrar como bloque, pero viene precedida por otra que indica que no se muestre (esto no tiene mucha razón de ser)
- Quitale ese color blanco a la fuente hace difícil que notes lo que ocurre por al momento con el ejemplo puesto empata con el color de la ventana y *se pierde*
- Aunque no es un error *perse* estás haciendo que los elementos sean flotantes, considero que será mucho mas simple apoyarte de *flexbox*

**Propongo**

En escencia es el mismo resultado pero realicé los siguientes cambios:

- Cambié las etiquetas de maquetación por las que tienen mayor relación semántica con un menú de navegación
- Re escribí las clases usadas para darles mejor manejo y que denoten el agrupamiento de elementos
- Para lograr que los elementos del menú reaccionen a un acomodo distinto hice:

  - Establecí una media query
  - Dentro de la media query invoco por medio de su clase al contenedor de los elementos **`li`** y le indico que ahora los elementos queden apilados uno sobre otro

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
      }
      .container-item {
        flex: auto;
        border: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 501px) {
        .container {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <nav>
      <ul class="container">
        <a class="container-item" href="#"> 
          <img class="container-item__logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" /> 
        </a>
        <a class="container-item" href="#about">Nosotros</a>
        <a class="container-item" href="#calidad">Calidad</a>
        <a class="container-item" href="#products">Productos</a>
        <a class="container-item" href="#contact">Contacto</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```